How to Configure RAID6 on ASUS RS720A-E12-RS12 with Broadcom MegaRAID 9560-16i?
I’m trying to set up a RAID6 array on my ASUS RS720A-E12-RS12 server. The system is equipped with a Broadcom MegaRAID 9560-16i controller and 12 NVMe SSDs (Intel DC P4610 1.6TB U.2 Series SSDPE2KE016T801, 2.5").
Here’s the setup:

The RAID controller is connected using the cable set (90SKS000-M3PAN0) as per the manual.
In the BIOS, all 12 disks are visible.
However, through the RAID controller, I can only see 4 disks, while the remaining 8 disks appear to be connected to the motherboard.

What I need help with:

Steps to configure RAID 6 using the Broadcom MegaRAID 9560-16i for all 12 NVMe drives.
Ensuring compatibility and optimal performance for the Intel DC P4610 SSDs.
Any specific firmware or driver updates needed for this setup.
BIOS or controller settings that I might be missing to make all 12 drives accessible via the RAID controller.

I’ve been through the documentation but couldn’t find a clear solution.

Check the backplane and its cabling - it needs to support all your drives and be connected to the 9560 only.
